# How can I define Excel time format as hhmm (no :)

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, for the date pattern, the mm is month unless it's :mm and then it's minutes. I need to display time as hhmm (no semicolon). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Sample]

You can simply set the Custom Format to `hhmm` as shown above;

If you want to show the result in a different cell,

Try

```
=TEXT(GivenTime,"hhmm")
```